# mass add time in a file

Tags: php, regex, datetime

i have a file in which time appears nearly hundred times
like

```
00:01:32
00:01:33
00:01:36
.......................
```

how can i add 2 seconds or 2 minutes to all the times in the file so that i get

```
00:01:34
00:01:35
00:01:38
..................
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_replace` with the `e` modifier to make it execute code to determine the replacement, then `strtotime` can parse it and do the necessary adjustments:

```
$data = preg_replace('/([0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})/e', 'modify_time("$1")', $data);

function modify_time($time) {
  return date('H:i:s', strtotime('+2 seconds', strtotime($time)));
}
```

Comment: strtotime can fail with TZ issues

Comment: thanks a lot man
you are genius
will you please add me on msn or yahoo
atinder_kool@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's elementary school question, how to add some minutes to the certain time. this text can be easily parsed into array with seconds and then adding certain amount of seconds to it's each member wouldnt be  a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

```
$min=date("i")+2;
if ($min<10)
{
    $min="0".$min;
}
$time= date("H:").$min;
echo $time;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('yourfile.txt', 'r');
$fpr=fopen('result.txt','a');
while (!feof($fp))
{
$mytext = fgets($fp, 9);
echo $mytext."<br />";
$result = substr($mytext,-2,2);

if ($result<=60)
{
    $result=$result+2;
    $result=substr($mytext,1,5).$result;
    echo $result."<br>";
    fwrite($fpr, $result);
}
else
{ 
    if ($result==58)
    $result="00";

    if ($result==59)
    $result="01";

    if ($result==60)
    $result="02";


    $result=substr($mytext,1,5).$result;
    echo $result."<br>";
    fwrite($fpr, $result);

}

}

?>
```